Applying Sitecore cumulative hotfix configurations from 'examples' directory
When applying Sitecore XP cumulative hotfixes, there are a number of configuration files located within the Examples directory.
According to Sitecore's instructions, we are advised to remove the .example extension from the files within the Examples directory.

My questions are:

After removing the .example extension, should we not add these files back into the Examples directory?

Should we instead place these configuration files in a separate directory, such as a zzz folder, to ensure they are loaded after other configurations? This would allow these files to override or extend existing settings as needed.


I am currently considering applying these files as part of a gulp task in our local installation. However, the documentation is not entirely clear on the recommended directory for placing these files after removing the extension.
Would it be advisable for Sitecore to clarify this process in their documentation?
For reference, here's an example of what the documentation currently states:


Sitecore applies config patches in the order defined in the layers.config file, as per this article:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/platform-administration-and-architecture/configuration-layers.html
In that article you will see that the Custom layer defaults to the App_Config/Include folder. Due to the fact that the examples folder is a child of that folder, then if you switch file extension from .example to .config as literally advised, then the patch would be applied, assuming no other patch  (in ZZZ for example) reversed the change.
That being said, it would make better sense to move the updated configuration file to a better location to reside with the other patches. Some people prefer to group Sitecore Support patches in the same folder.
